# Automatically merge related items when deserializing

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am  currently building a simple REST API with Symfony 4.

I have an entity named `News` which has a ManyToOne relationship with an entity `Startup`.

```
// News.php

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Startup", inversedBy="news")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $startup;


// Startup.php

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\News", mappedBy="startup", orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $news;
```

I am building an endpoint to add a new News (which has to be related to one startup).

So  I am currently sending a POST request with this kind of body data

```
{
    "title": "this is my title",
    "startup": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "My Startup"
    }
}
```

The startup *My Startup* with the id 1 exists in my database, but Doctrine is detecting it as a new one, trying to persist a new Startup too (as the Startup object is detached from the entity manager when sending through JSON).

**Is there any way to automatically re-attached the startup object for Doctrine to understand that I need to persist the new News with the existing Startup ?** (*automatically means that I do not want to manually query the database to get the attached object*)

Answer (score 0):

You can use doctrine [merge](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#merging-entities) to re-attach a deserialized object.

```
$detachedEntity = unserialize($serializedEntity); // some detached entity
$entity = $em->merge($detachedEntity);
```

Comment: This is what I called manually because you need to do it for every related entity you have in an object.